# How to Check data is int, float in python

Tags: python

I know similar questions have been asked and answered before like here: How do I check if a string is a number (float or Int ) in Python?

However, it does not provide the answer I'm looking for. What I'm trying to do is this:

```py
def is_int_or_float(s):
    try:
        a = float(s)
        return 1 if s.count('.')==0 else 2
    except ValueError:
        return -1

val = input("Enter your value: ")
data = is_int_or_float(val) 
print(data)
```

What if User enters =>  "22"  # Then Above code will gives -1.Please help me to resolve this With Exception handling (User Message)

Comment: exactly what is the rationale behind `s.count('.') == 0`...

Comment: If a numeric string has at least one decimal point, it's likely a float. Not perfect but I understand the intent

Comment: If a user enters a quoted number (e.g. "22") then you want to strip the quotes off, right?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: I think the quotes are part of the string literal. But I guess the question is not very clear... It seems to have to return something different for an integral number versus a decimal number.

Comment: I imagine the intended behavior is that it returns 1 if the string has an int, 2 if the string has a float, and -1 if the string has neither

Comment: If user enters 1e-4 it passes being a float but has no '.' in it so returns "1" but should be "2" since value is 0.0001.

Comment: It also errors on integral floats such as `22.0`. Using `float.is_integer` is a more versatile answer

Comment: Although if OP is *literally* trying to enter `"22"` into the `input()` prompt, then they have a different issue entirely

Comment: @Wilson - please post a table to your question that shows examples of literal user inputs in one column and expected response in another column so the answer solves your problem. Not clear if your function should allow quoted numbers or if 1.0 should be treated as an integer or a float returning 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
def is_int_or_float(value):
    try:
        tmp = float(value)
        return 1 if tmp.is_integer() else 2
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

And testing:

```
>>> is_int_or_float("a")
-1
>>> is_int_or_float("22") 
1
>>> is_int_or_float("22.646") 
2
>>> is_int_or_float("22.64.6") 
-1
>>> is_int_or_float("22.000")  
1
>>> is_int_or_float("1e-4")
2
```

Comment: BTW, I think the `tmp` variable is not needed and you do the cast to float in the return.

Comment: It's absolutely not needed, but I figured clear is better than concise.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple handle for that.

Check the code. You need to implements you exception handle logic.

```
class AbstractHandler:
    def is_float(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def is_int(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def verify(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Handler(AbstractHandler):
    def is_float(self, number):
        try:
            float(number)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            # Your exception handler here
            return False

    def is_int(self, number):
        try:
            int(number)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            # Your exception handler here
            return False

    def verify(self, var):
        if self.is_float(var) or self.is_int(var):
            return True
        else:
            return False


def is_number(var):
    """
        Verify if input is a instance of int or float
    Args:
        var (str): input to be verified
    """
    handler = Handler()
    return handler.verify(var)
```

Some tests:

```
1 is True
1.1 is True
1.1.1 is False
```

Answer (score -3):

One way to check, for example integer, use **isinstance**:

```
x = 1
if isinstance(x, int):
    # Do something
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what OP is looking for.... It seems they have a `str` and they want to know if the thing it represents is an int or a float